# Azure Data Factory: Flattening/normalizing a cloumn from CSV file using Azure Data Factory activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have pulled a csv file from one of our source using ADF and there is one column called "attributes" which contains multiple fields (in the form of key value pairs). Now I want to expand that column into different fields (columns). Below is the sample of that:

```
leadId  activityDate    activityTypeId  campaignId  primaryAttributeValue   attributes
1234    2020-06-22T00:00:44Z    46  33686   Mail    {"Description":"Clicked: https://stepuptostepout.com/","Source":"Lead action","Date":"2020-06-21 19:00:44"}
5678    2020-06-22T00:01:54Z    13  33128   SMS {"Reason":"Changed","New Value":110,"Old Value":null,"Source":"Marketo Flow Action"}
```

Here the attributes column have different Key-value pairs and I want them in different column so that I can store them in Azure SQL Database:

attributes
{"Reason":"Changed","New Value":110,"Old Value":null,"Source":"Marketo"}

I want them as:

```
Reason     New Value    Old Value   Source
Changed    110          null        Marketo
```

I am using Azure Data Factory. Please help!

Updating this:
One more thing I have noticed in my data is that the keys are not uniform, also if there is one key (say 'Source') present for one lead ID it might not be present/missing in the other leadId, making this more complicated. Hence having a separate column for each Attribute Key might not be a good idea.
Thus, we can have a separate table for 'attribute' field with lead ID, AttributeKey, AttributeValue as columns (we can join this with our main table using LeadID). The Attribute table will look like:

```
LeadID AttributeKey AttributeValue
5678 Reason Changed
5678 New Value 110
5678 Old Value null
5678 Source Marketo
```

Can you help me I can I achieve this using ADF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data flow to do this thing.Below is my test sample.

[image]

- **Setting of source1**
  [image]
- **Setting of Filter1**

> instr(attributes,'Reason') != 0

- **Setting of DerivedColumn1**

  [image]

Here is my expression and it's complex.

> @(Reason=translate(split(split(attributes,',')[1],':')[2],'"',''),
> NewValue=translate(split(split(attributes,',')[2],':')[2],'"',''),
> OldValue=translate(split(split(attributes,',')[3],':')[2],'"',''),
> Source=translate(translate(split(split(attributes,',')[4],':')[2],'"',''),'}',''))

- **Setting of Select1**
  [image]

Here is the result:
[image]

By the way,if your file is json,may be simple to do this than csv.
Hope this can help you:).

Comment: Thanks Steve! This was really helpful.